# Android and Fragment result API. How to share result from child fragment with different request key?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, activity-result-api

I am trying to implement fragment result API in my application. I need to show DialogFragment inside Fragment and send result from dialog fragment to fragment when dialog buttons was clicked.
So in my dialog fragment when button was clicked I making smth like this:

```
  setFragmentResult(requestKey, bundleOf(RESULT to result))
```

And I'am trying to retrieve result in my fragment inside `onCreate()`:

```
  childFragmentManager.setFragmentResultListener(requestKey, this) { _, bundle ->
        val result = bundle.getInt(DialogFragment.RESULT)
       // some code
    }
```

Everything works well, but there is one problem. The `requestKey` I use when calling the `setFragmentResult` in my dialog fragment is dynamic.

That is, the dialog can be opened inside the fragment in different cases. And I need to distinguish between these cases. To do this, I send a different request key to the dialog fragment.
But how do I, when receiving a result in a fragment, distinguish this result by key. If I do this inside the `onCreate()` method.

That is, I want to do something like this:

```
 childFragmentManager.setFragmentResultListener(requestKey, this) { requestKey, bundle ->
            when(requestKey) {
                "FIRST_CASE" -> { // some code }
                "SECOND_CASE" -> { // some code }  
          }
        }
```

But I do not understand how this can be implemented if this method (`setFragmentResultListener`) already requires a `requestKey` as an argument. Where should I take it from?

If my `requestKey` was static I would create a constant inside the dialog fragment and use it. But my `requestKey` is dynamic.

Please help me. I did not find a suitable example for me on the Internet. And at the moment I don’t understand how this can be implemented in the context of a clean architecture with MVVM.

P.S. Here is an example of what I want to implement:
A fragment that contains two buttons (e.g. `A`, `B`). By clicking on each of the buttons, dialog fragment opens, with different text. Inside the dialog there is also a button, by clicking on which the result is transferred to the fragment. I need to process this result differently, depending on which button was pressed on the fragment (A or B). To do this, I wanted to distinguish by request key.

Comment: Why does it need to be dynamic at all? Your caller can already keep track of which of two requests are in flight without your dialog having to know anything.

Answer (score 2):

The reason the `FragmentResultListener` received a `requestKey` is if you are reusing the same `FragmentResultListener` in **multiple** calls to `setFragmentResultListener` - i.e., if your Fragment itself implemented `FragmentResultListener`.

In your case, your Fragment isn't implementing the `FragmentResultListener`, so you can just call `setFragmentResultListener` twice, once for each key:

```
childFragmentManager.setFragmentResultListener("FIRST_CASE", this) { _, bundle ->
  // some code
}
childFragmentManager.setFragmentResultListener("SECOND_CASE", this) { _, bundle ->
  // some code
}
```